# how to balance tomcat webservice by nginx?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, tomcat, nginx

I config the nginx to balance tomcat webservice use IP_Hash, but it always redirect to a fixed tomcat, when I use different IP? How to config it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about IP_Hash but I have been configuring load balancing as shown on [nbginx website](http://wiki.nginx.org/LoadBalanceExample) and it worked well:

Basically: (copied from the link above)

```
http {
  upstream myproject {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000 weight=3;
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
  server 127.0.0.1:8002;    
  server 127.0.0.1:8003;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.domain.com;
   location / {
    proxy_pass http://myproject;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your method but it cannot share the session on webservice, and the 
nginx-upstream-jvm-route is faild!

Comment: if you need session sharing, shouldn't you use clustering at the tomcat level ?

Comment: Session sharing well on webapp, but it cannot work well on webservices!

Comment: My webservice port 18777,28777 and tomcat port 18080,28080,  upstream myproject {
  server 127.0.0.1:18777;
  server 127.0.0.1:28777;
  server 127.0.0.1:38777;    
  server 127.0.0.1:48777;
}

Comment: how do you deploy your webservices ?

Answer (score 0):

We deployed the webservice as a war file written in Java. And we request web service by C# client application.

Answer (score 0):

Are any nginx modules that actually look at Tomcat application servers, and do load balancing based on real *load*, rather than just doing simple round-robin?